# Animating a growing low poly tree

Tags: animation

[image: g lo]

How should I go about animating a growing tree?

Just using scaling and shrinkwraping does make it look kind of like it's "growing" but it's not how a tree really should grow.

My idea is, to have the tree go from a single twig as a sapling, then adding on new branches and "leaves" as it grows further. If I just scale it, then a fully grown tree looks the same as a sapling, just bigger (duh) so it doesn't really feel like it's growing.

I can't get shape keys to work, as I would need to increase/reduce the amount of vertices and also, I'm using the skin modifier, but I can't get the vertex radiuses to animate to make the branches thicker/thinner.

Is there an easier way than just manualy animatin every single vertex? Maybe if I make intermediate models and transition between them if that's possible?

Also as an extra, would it be also possible to add on bones as the tree develops, as to add wind effects and other interactions?

Comment: why not bones and use their scale to make the tree fatten or scale on the Z axis etc?

Comment: that does work, but at some point I would like to transition from a straight twig to a developed tree and I'm not sure if I can just add a bone to an armature in the middle of an animation.

Comment: you can juste align all your bones at the beginning then they begin to grow and rotate, I've given a try it's pretty easy to do

Comment: okay I'll give it a try and see how it goes!

Comment: if you have any difficulty let me know

Comment: okay I managed to get it to work and look kind of okay-ish. I'll post the results in a bit!

Comment: Post the result as an answer. It's a valid method and should be seen between the answers =)

Answer (score 2):

So I'll just post this as an answer but if anybody has a better suggestion feel free to share!

So I managed to get it to work thanks to [moonboots's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) comment

[image: Growing tree]

As suggested I made an armature and just scaled down each branch seperatley and then rotated it so it's hidden inside the mesh. It looks fine from a distance but not so great up close

[image: Up close view of branches inside the mesh]